# Как запарсить данные в соответсвии с условием?

Tags: javascript, парсер

Есть сайт с которого нужно запарсить данные со следующим условием. если в таблице крайняя правая ячейка соответсвует A+,A++ или B+,B++ , то крайний левая ячейка выводится в консоль(с тикером компании).
Вот ссылка на сайт https://etfdb.com/screener/
Заранее спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, например `document.querySelectorAll('[data-th="ETFdb Pro"]').forEach(node => console.log(node.innerText))` выведет в консоль все значения правого столбца. Вместо этого нужно сравнить его с нужными значениями и при необходимости взять из той же строки первую ячейку - это уж как-нибудь сами.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, информацию о природе парсера: он будет работать в коде самого сайта (это ваш сайт), через букмарклет или пользовательский скрипт, через расширение браузера, как локальная утилита на Node.js?

Comment: в коде самого сайта

Comment: Yaant,
document.querySelectorAll('[data-th="ETFdb Pro"]').forEach(node => console.log(node.innerText));
document.querySelectorAll('[data-th="Symbol"]').forEach(tiker => console.log(tiker.innerText));
а вот как их сравнить по условию я не знаю. Подскажи пожалуйста!

Comment: Не стоит задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, вам удобнее будет перебирать строки и проверять/выводить их ячейки:

```
const rows = document.querySelector('div#mobile_table_pills table')
                     .querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

for (const row of rows) {
  const lastCellText = row.querySelector('[data-th="ETFdb Pro"]').innerText;
  if ( lastCellText === 'A+' || lastCellText === 'B+') {
    console.log(row.querySelector('[data-th="Symbol"]').innerText);
  }
}
```

Comment: вместо дублирования ответа, нужно было закрыть как дубликат